# How tell who deleted an answer and when?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

My question [Plural cref to theorem-like environment, singular cref to enumerate item inside it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366244/plural-cref-to-theorem-like-environment-singular-cref-to-enumerate-item-inside) had had an extended answer by @Mico. That answer disappeared as soon as I added a comment to the answer about the method failing in certain situations.

How can I tell who deleted the answer, and when?

Comment: I think any user with more than 10K reputation can see that (probably @Mico deleted his answer by himself).

Comment: I will temporarily delete an answer if it has significant problems that I hadn't noticed. I suspect Mico may have deleted his answer for this reason too. The answer may reappear when the problem is fixed (because answers are never truly deleted, just made invisible to <10k users) or it may stay deleted if he thinks it doesn't actually solve your problem.

Comment: We can see the answer and your comments and also his last comment but I think @Mico is the one that should address this question. Because it looks like you weren't satisfied with the answer and he didn't want to modify further his answer.

Comment: Mico deleted his answer, that's possible to see for users with more than 10k reputation. Otherwise answers are deleted only in a flagging review by other delete votings, but that occurs only if the answer is really bad. Moderators can delete answers directly, but won't do without reasons -- none of the given reasons by me is apparently true for Mico's answer. Perhaps the O.P. changed the question such that Mico's answer did not not work any longer or he was just unsatisified with it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Neither @Mico nor I had tried the "addendum" version of the cross-reference link in a different chapter from the chapter with the link's target; hence the issue. But he did provide an earlier answer that is still of some help.

Answer (score 5):

This was [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366257/5764) deleted by its owner ([Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)):

[image]

Such views (like the one above) are only available to users with at least 10K reputation as part of the [moderator tools privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). However, it is still included in the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). The following query extracts all the answers to your question - referenced by `ParentId = 366244` (found via the `share` link at the bottom of your question, or the question URL):

```
SELECT *
FROM PostsWithDeleted
WHERE ParentId = 366244;
```

Note that the SEDE lags by about 1 week.

Comment: Is the little clock and the registered flag below the profile picture  something that trusted users get, or is this some user script?

Comment: @Johannes_B: It's a user script called [SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox).

Comment: Thank you, i am just trying it out.